# Redis-cli not able to change the redis.conf?

Tags: redis

I am learning redis, and I am trying to modify the persistence setting via redis-cli.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG get save
1) "save"
2) "3600 1 300 100 60 10000"
```

When I execute this command,

```
CONFIG set save "60 1"
```

I am able to change the  save parameter, but it is not reflecting in redis.conf file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to persist your configuration changes you'll need to call [`CONFIG REWRITE`](http://redis.io/commands/config-rewrite)